# Change variable in array of objects in state React

Tags: reactjs

What I wanted to do is whenever I click button to change variable in states array of objects. I did it this way, but is there any easier way to do it?

```
completeItem = (id) => {
     const item = this.state.items.filter(el =>{
          return el.id === id;
      });

      item[0].isCompleted = true;
      const state = this.state.items;
      const arr = this.state.items.filter(el =>{
          if(el.id === id){
              state[id-1] = item[0];
          }
          return state;
      });
      this.setState({
          items:[...arr],
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution...

```
 completeItem = (id) => {
     const items = this.state.items.filter(el =>{
         if(el.id === id){
             el.isCompleted = true;
          }
         return el;
     });
     this.setState({
         items : [...items],
     });
  }
```

If the solution is helpful please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

May compromise a little performance, but it is more readable.

```js
completeItem = (id) => {
   const newList = [...this.state.items]
   const index = newList.findIndex(el => el.id === id);
   newList[index].isCompleted = true
   this.setState({ items: newList });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "one",
    isCompleted: false
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "two",
    isCompleted: false
},

{
    id: 3,
    name: "three",
    isCompleted: false
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "four",
    isCompleted: false
}
]

completeItem = (id) => {
const result = items.map(e => {
    if (e.id === id) {
        return { ...e,
            isCompleted: true
        }
    } else {
        return e;
    }
});
console.log(result)
}

completeItem(2)
```